# Object reference not set to an instance of an object. When browsing to local site

Tags: iis, iis-7.5, umbraco

i am getting this error when i try and navigate to my local dev site. but not sure what the exception is pointing. I've got the site set up in IIS similar to another site that works fine.

```
[NullReferenceException: Object reference not set to an instance of an object.]
umbraco.requestHandler..ctor(XmlDocument umbracoContent, String url) +3727
umbraco.UmbracoDefault.Page_PreInit(Object sender, EventArgs e) +1217
System.EventHandler.Invoke(Object sender, EventArgs e) +0
System.Web.UI.Page.PerformPreInit() +48
System.Web.UI.Page.ProcessRequestMain(Boolean includeStagesBeforeAsyncPoint, Boolean includeStagesAfterAsyncPoint) +1843
```

Comment: Can you access the backoffice at `~/umbraco`? If so, republish your content structure and try again.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The reason for this error is usually a missing or incomplete XML cache file which is located in the App_Data directory and called umbraco.config. Is this a new clean site with no content? If so then you need to login and publish something first. If you do have content then might I suggest regenerating the XML cache file by navigation to http://{yourhostname}/umbraco/dialogs/republish.aspx?xml=true

For further reference also see http://our.umbraco.org/wiki/reference/api-cheatsheet/publishing-and-republishing

Answer (score -1):

`NullReferenceException` is thrown when you try to use a member or method of an object which is null. You need to initialize your relevant object before you use its members and methods. You should carefully check your code at the points shown in the trace pasted, find out why the exception is thrown and fix the problem.